# connection partially encrypted, SSL for perl app

Tags: https, httpd.conf

I am getting error on FireFox "connection partially encrypted" other browsers show that's not encrypted...
 When I setup apache with ssl I use "/var/www/html/" for default directory, but all scripts are in /var/www/cgi-bin/ so is there a problem? or I'am on wrong way?
But when switch to "/var/www/" I get an default CentOS web. (Like new server)

Maybe, someone have an ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Strelson

Comment: Your page is likely referencing a part (image, frame, etc) by an absolute reference (ie http://example.com/image.png). All page content must be encrypt for the "connection" to be encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to view page source in Firefox
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and enter `http:` to find the resources requested from a non-SSL connection
3. Correct references to unsecured resources (you can use URI's of the form `//domain.com/resource` to avoid specifying HTTP/SSL)